# How to read the size of a big bitmap image

Tags: c++, bitmap, binary, hex, decimal

I'm having problems reading big bitmap images. Note that this is a 24bit BMP file.
So I have an image with a size of 800x600.
In the file, where it tells the width and height I get this.

Width (4 bytes):

```
20 03 00 00
```

Height (4 bytes):

```
58 02 00 00
```

I have exported both with Paint.NET and MS Paint programs. Both had the same output.
It seems that when images get big, the calculations get wrong.
With small images (100x100 and so) the results are what I want.
I have tested changing the size manually (width=800;) and it works perfectly for what I need.
What I do is sum all the bytes and put together on an integer.

Example: (I store the file on a vector called store):

```
unsigned int width = store[0x12] + store[0x13] + store[0x14] + store[0x15];
```

I then made the program create a file to tell me how width was stored.

```
ofstream s("hht.txt");
        s <<  width;
        s << "\n";
        s << dec << width;
        s << "\n";
        s << hex << width;
        s.close();
```

This is the output I get:

```
35
35
23
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

**NOTE**: 
-The width info is at location 0x12 and height is at 0x16. 
-The file is 800x600. 
-I don't know how the height is, but I know it is wrong as well.

Comment: Try `store[0x12] + store[0x13] << 8 + store[0x14] << 16 + store[0x15] << 24` and see how it goes.

Comment: When you see a number like 1024, do you add 1+0+2+4?

Comment: @n.m. I don't think I made myself clear. I'm not adding 2+0+3+0+0, what I'm doing is getting the hex values, not text. The file is in hex, not ascii.

Comment: @PeterJ still gives me 0.

Comment: try `width = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(&store[0x12])` ;)

Comment: @j_kubik omg. Thank you a lot. It worked! Please make your comment an answer. Can you tell me where can I get more info about this? And what about store[0x13] and store[0x14] and store[0x15]? BTW, I switched uint32_t to int*.

Comment: Ok let me ask a different question. When you see a large number like 65,536 you don't add 65+536 (decimal numbers) do you? Yet you have added 20+03+00+00 (hexadecimal numbers).

Comment: @user3804254: You are looking at 32-bit _little-endian_ hexadecimal numbers. 0x00000320 equals 800 in decimal, and 0x00000258 is 600.

Comment: It is not enough to be an answer here, and I am too lazy to explain memory layout of variables here - you will probably find something about it on the net :P. As was already pointed out, read about variable sizes and little-endian machines.

Comment: @n.m. :) Sorry, but I'm not understanding your question. The number is 800, and it's stored as 20 03 00 00. What I wanted was to get the decimal from it. Seems like the solution was what j_kubik said. I should say it again, that the file is in hex, not ascii.

Comment: BTW What I wrote breaks aliasing rules, so it might fail to work under certain circumstances...

Comment: Why did you assume it was stored in ASCI?

Comment: @j_kubik I didn't assume it was in ASCII. It just sounded to me that n.m. was talking about ascii. I always knew that it was in hex.

Comment: In your code, you are adding hex 20 and hex 3 together, giving you hex 23/dec 35. Dec 800 is hex 320. The values are little endian, and you need to be reading in the hex 03 as dec 768.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of 10-base numbers and 16-base numbers? Do you realize that 00000320 in hexadecimal is 800 decimal? Why are you adding 00+00+03+20 and not 8+00?

Comment: What people are trying to tell you, that you're misinterpreting as ASCII, is that you don't simply add the digits of a number to get a number. For decimal 800 you add 8*100 + 0*10 + 0*1 to get 800. For hex 320 you add 3*256 + 2*16 + 0*1 to get 800. It was an analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with how you're computing the width.

```
unsigned int width = store[0x12] + store[0x13] + store[0x14] + store[0x15];
```

What you are doing here with your example of width is this:

```
unsigned int width = 0x20 + 0x03 + 0x00 + 0x00; // width = 0x23
```

Which is this in decimal:

```
unsigned int width = 32 + 3 + 0 + 0; // width = 35
```

This doesn't get you the real value of 20 03 00 00 because in this case 03 isn't supposed to represent 0x03, it's supposed to represent 0x0300 (768 in decimal).

Why does this work with small numbers? The answer would be that you would be adding together one number with 3 pairs of zeros in the digits that would normally need to be multiplied to get their real values. (Example: width of 32 would be 20 00 00 00, which would add together 0x20 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 to get 0x20, which is still 32 in decimal)

If you haven't noticed yet, the bitmap holds the values in little-endian order. In other words, the value of width together would not be 0x20030000 (537067520 in decimal), it would be 0x00000320 (800 in decimal, the width of your bitmap).

```
width = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(&store[0x12])
```

may work in this case, but not only might this break the aliasing rules, this will only work on your implementation if uints are little-endian as well. If they are big-endian, your width would be calculated as 0x20030000 (537067520) instead of 0x00000320 (800).